# How to change the zoom when create a route to other points?

Tags: typescript, leaflet

At the moment, when creating a route, the zoom occurs on the created route, but I need to zoom to certain points (an array of `customPoints` objects). I do not understand how to create my own layer with `customPoints` and zoom in on them.

```
routeLayer: L.GeoJSON;
customPointsLayer: L.GeoJSON;

addRoute(data) {
     let features = data['features'];
     var geoJsonMarkerOptions = {radius: 5, color: blue};
     this.routeLayer = L.geoJSON(features, {
      pointToLayer: function(feature, latLng) { return L.circleMarker(latLng, geoJsonMarkerOptions); }
     }).addTo(this.map); 
     this.customPointsLayer = L.GeoJSON().addTo(this.map);
     this.map.fitBounds(this.nearestPointsLayer.getBounds());
}
```